# Is there a FME Spatial Filter test for "centroid is completely within"?

Tags: fme-form

Using SAFE FME I am trying to select all polygons from featureclass A whose centerpoints are "completely within" polyon B. Being used to ArcGIS I would have thought this would be available as a test with the Spatial Filter but there are only limited options here. Does anyone know how I could create this filter?

Comment: I don't know FME but I would guess that by creating a helper layer from the centroids as points with the same IDs as the polygons and doing a "within" test

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CenterPointReplacer then the SpatialFilter. Alternatively the PointOnAreaOverlayer will do a point-in-polygon test